# Pivot table using 2 data ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

is it possible to have a single pivot table that combines 2 worksheets as the data?

For example, first data table will be made up of the following columns:

ID/Details/Category

The second data table will be made up of the following columns:

ID/Customer name

The reason why the 2 tables are not combined is because there may be many customer names to the same customer name.

I want a pivot table that will show me the following things:

1) Be able to sort by ID and see for each ID the details linked to that ID sorted by category 
2) Be able to sort by customer name and see the details linked to that customer sort by category.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it's easier to add a CustomerName column into the Table1, VLOOKUP values from Table2 and make a pivot table from Table1.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+D+P. Select multiple consolidation ranges, choose your two ranges of data, and you've got it.